# Refactoring JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble refactoring my vanilla JavaScript to jQuery and would appreciate any and all help regarding my situation. I'm a bit stuck on how to refactor the albumImage function (and everything inside it) after having refactored the DOM selectors in the first code block to jQuery syntax.

```
var setCurrentAlbum = function(album) {
  $albumTitle.text(album.title);
  $albumArtist.text(album.artist);
  $albumReleaseInfo.text(album.year + ' ' + album.label);
  $albumImage.attr('src', album.albumArtUrl);
  $albumSongList.empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < album.songs.length; i++) {
  var $newRow = createSongRow(i + 1, album.songs[i].title, album.songs[i].duration);
    $albumSongList.append($newRow);
    }
};


var $albums=[album1, album2, album3];
var $index = 1;

$albumImage.on("click",function(event){
  setCurrentAlbum($albums[index]); 
  index++; 
  if ($index == $albums.length) { 
    $index = 0;
};
});
```

Comment: From native code to jQuery? You're going the wrong direction. If you have working code, why burden it with dependencies and overhead? I mean unless you still support IE7 or something.

Comment: @squint This is in an attempt to learn how to work with both native code and jQuery :)

Comment: `index` and `$index` are not the same. `$index` never increments. Not really a jquery problem.

Comment: @PatrickBarr The expected behavior would be to have the page function as it would with native code, but with these attempts I've made, it doesn't open properly :(

Comment: What are album1/2/3?  Are the Elements or jQuery elements?

Comment: @JacobYun *"The expected behavior would be to have the page function as it would with native code"* still doesn't tell us what this code should be doing and what it's doing instead. It just says "I has a problem" without telling us what the problem is.

Comment: @Taplar Currently they are elements

Comment: Then you need to wrap them in $() before you can use jquery methods off of them like text and attr, etc.

Comment: @JacobYun i believe you are mistaken. If they are elements, then they don't have .text() and other jquery methods.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry for unclear questions, bit new to stack community..  Let me try and rephrase it as so: The function should allow user to cycle through albums 1, 2, and 3 by clicking on the album image. But as of now the album image nor the relevant information loads with the page.

Comment: that's still no better than "it doesn't work." ***why*** doesn't it work. Where does it fail. What errors are occuring.